# Error replacing play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise with scala.concurrent.Promise

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to upgrade from Play 2.1.3 to 2.2.0 and I am getting an error while trying to compile.  The main change was that play.api.libs.concurrent.Promise is deprecated and was instructed to replace it with scala.concurrent.Promise.  The compilation error is below:

Error Message:

```
WebSocketJoin.scala:23: object creation impossible, since method fold in trait Iteratee of type [B](folder: play.api.libs.iteratee.Step[A,B] => scala.concurrent.Future[B])(implicit ec: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext)scala.concurrent.Future[B] is not defined
[error]         def wrap(delegate: Iteratee[A, B]): Iteratee[A, B] = new Iteratee[A, B] {
[error]                                                                  ^
[error] one error found
[error] (adapter-api/compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Code:

```
package utils

import play.api.libs.iteratee.{Step, Enumerator, Iteratee}
import scala.concurrent.{Promise, ExecutionContext, Future}
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object WebSocketJoin {

  /**
   * Create a joined iteratee enumerator pair.
   *
   * When the enumerator is applied to an iteratee, the iteratee subsequently consumes whatever the iteratee in the pair
   * is applied to.  Consequently the enumerator is "one shot", applying it to subsequent iteratees will throw an
   * exception.
   */
  def joined[A]: (Iteratee[A, Unit], Enumerator[A]) = {
    val promisedIteratee = Promise[Iteratee[A, Unit]]()
    val enumerator = new Enumerator[A] {
      def apply[B](i: Iteratee[A, B]) = {
        val doneIteratee = Promise[Iteratee[A, B]]()

        // Equivalent to map, but allows us to handle failures
        def wrap(delegate: Iteratee[A, B]): Iteratee[A, B] = new Iteratee[A, B] {
          def fold[C](folder: (Step[A, B]) => Future[C]) = {
            val toReturn = delegate.fold {
              case done @ Step.Done(a, in) => {
                doneIteratee.success(done.it)
                folder(done)
              }
              case Step.Cont(k) => {
                folder(Step.Cont(k.andThen(wrap)))
              }
              case err => folder(err)
            }
            toReturn.onFailure {
              case e => doneIteratee.failure(e)
            }
            toReturn
          }
        }

        if (promisedIteratee.trySuccess(wrap(i).map(_ => ()))) {
          doneIteratee.future
        } else {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Joined enumerator may only be applied once")
        }
      }
    }
    (Iteratee.flatten(promisedIteratee.future), enumerator)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The joined iteratee/enumerator pair that I posted on my blog post is now available in Play 2.2.0 as `play.api.libs.iteratee.Concurrent.joined`.  Switch to that and you can delete the above code from your code base.

To fix your code by the way, modify the method on line 24 to accept an implicit ExecutionContext.  Play 2.2 changed the iteratee API so that many things now accept exception contexts:

```
def fold[C](folder: (Step[A, B]) => Future[C])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
```